# msbuild fails for 4.5.2

Tags: c#, msbuild

I'm trying to get a deployment script running for a project using the framework version 4.5.2.
Unfortunately, I get build errors when I try to build the project with `msbuild`. It complains everywhere I'm using on of the new "shortcuts", for Example `exception?.ToString()`.

Obviously the framework at build time is wrong configured. As far as I've understood the the Command Line Reference at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164311.aspx, my call should be correct.

```
%MSBUILD_HOME%\msbuild "%REPOSITORY_DIR%\Project.csproj" /p:Configuration=Release;TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.5.2;VisualStudioVersion=14.0
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please make sure you are using the msbuild.exe coming with VS2015.
By default it is c:\Program File(x86)\MSBUILD\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe

So your `%MSBUILD_HOME% should be c:\Program File(x86)\MSBUILD\14.0\bin`

> One final point to mention about all the C# 6.0 features is that although they obviously require the C# 6.0 compiler, included with Visual Studio 2015 or later, they do not require an updated version of the Microsoft .NET Framework. Therefore, you can use C# 6.0 features even if you’re compiling against the .NET Framework 4, for example. The reason this is possible is that all features are implemented in the compiler, and don’t have any .NET Framework dependencies.
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/Dn879355.aspx